# Designing Role and Groups Permission System - MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, nosql

I am working on ERM project and trying to think of suitable schema design for users, roles and groups in MongoDB`. I am novice in database design, and currently I have created this design.

- User can have one role
- User can be member of multiple groups
- Both roles and groups have separate permissions for each
- Both roles and groups can be added, deleted and updated
- User's permissions are calculated from role and groups

And the permission calculation for user is done like this:

Role [`USER` *update*] + Group [`USER` *view*] = User [`USER` *view, update*]
Role [`BLOG` *deny*] + Group [`BLOG` *view*] = User [`BLOG` *deny*]

The issue I'm facing is in permission calculation as this design would require permission calculation on every group/role change. And if the group contains hundreds of users, it can cause performance issues.

```
User {
    role: String
    permissions: [{
        resource: String,
        value: Number // Read(4), Edit(2), Create(8), Delete(1)
    }]
}

Role {
    name: String,
    permissions: [{
        type: String,
        ref: 'Permissions'  
    }]
}

PermissionGroup {
    name: String,
    users: [{
        type: String,
        ref: 'User' 
    }],
    permissions: [{
        type: String,
        ref: 'Permissions'  
    }]
}

Permissions {
    resource: String,
    value: Number // Read(4), Edit(2), Create(8), Delete(1)
}
```

I want to make this as efficient as possible because user permissions are used in authorizing each request. What are some best performance practices for this design?